# integral of $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm curious how my textbook got:

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}$$

to

$$\sin^{-1}(u)+ c$$

This considering that "$u$" could be simplified into $u = \sin(x)$

Thus we get:

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-\sin^2(u))}}$$

Which is further simplified into:

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(\cos^2(u))}}$$

Since: $$\cos^2(u) =\sqrt{(1-\sin^2(u)}$$

Meaning that we get:

$$\int \frac{du}{\cos(u)}$$

Which is not  *$\sin^{-1}(u)+ c$* when integrated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

So, when you make the substitution $u=\sin x$, you also need to make the substitution for $du$ as well:

$$du=\frac{du}{dx}dx=\cos xdx$$

Thus, the new integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\int \frac{dx\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}$$

Hopefully, you can take it from there.

Comment: I do get that. I should've maybe added that the original integral was :  $$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-(x-1)^2)}}$$  . The author then substitued $(x-1)$ with $u$ giving me $du  = dx$. We then get $$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-(u)^2)}}$$  where I can only think of substituting  $u = sin(u)$ using the pythagorean theorem.  Meaning that their(author) $du$ does not equate to $cosxdx$

Comment: @oxodo In this case, I would actually make a new variable $z$ and say $u=\sin z$. Then, you need to make the substitution using $du=\cos zdz$. Try evaluating the integral in terms of $z$ and see what you get. Then, you can substitute $z=\sin^{-1}u$ and $u=x-1$ back into your final solution.

Comment: Cheers. But why would you think of doing that? I mean since you have $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-(u)^2)}}$ shouldn't the obvious thing to do be to recognize that $\sqrt{(1-(u)^2})= cosu$? Thus leaving me with $\frac{du}{cosu)}$ hence $\int du(secu)$?

Comment: However, $\sqrt{1-u^2}\neq \cos u$. That equation is simply incorrect. I think you are basing this off $u=\sin u$, which is also clearly incorrect. If $u=\sin u$, then we could plug in $u=\pi$ and get $\pi=\sin \pi=0$, which is clearly a contradiction. This is why we have to make a new variable and say $u=\sin z$ instead of $u=\sin u$.

Comment: Hmm. So what is limiting this substitution by using pythagorean theorem  is that u cannot equal $\pi$?

Comment: @oxodo No, what is limiting the substitution $u=\sin u$ is that it is a straight-out false equation. You can not just use the equation $u=\sin u$ because it is simply not true. If you plug in any value of $u$ other than $u=0$ into that equation, you will get a contradiction ($u=\pi$ was simply one example.) This is why you need to create a new variable and say $u=\sin z$. Then, you can apply Pythagorean theorem to get $\sqrt{1-u^2}=\cos z$ and $du=\cos zdz$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$x=\sin u\Rightarrow dx=\cos u\,du$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int \frac{\cos u\,du}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}}$$
Recalling that $$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$$
We have
$$I=\int\frac{\cos u\,du}{\cos u}$$
$$I=\int du$$
$$I=u$$
$$I=\arcsin x+C$$